# Filter by date using materializecss on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I am trying to show all my items upon loading the page, and if the date is selected (using materializecss datepicker), to show only the date range of items. Showing all the items is easy as I just need to do @all_requests = Request.all, but I have spent two nights trying various methods like form_for and form_tag etc. Currently with the code below it shows only today's items because of the default Date.today, but if i remove the default it gives a nil error, I think because the date has not been selected yet...

Index.html.erb

```
 <%= form_tag requests_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_from]', @search.date_from, placeholder: 'From date', class: 'datepicker'  %>
   <%= text_field_tag 'search[date_to]', @search.date_to, placeholder: 'To date', class: 'datepicker' %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn waves-effect waves-light formbttn' %>
   <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <% @all_requests.each do |request| %>
    ...
```

Request.search.rb

```
class RequestSearch
  attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

  def initialize(params)
    params ||= {}
    date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], Date.today.to_s)
    date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.today.to_s)
  end

  def scope
    Request.where(:date => 'date_from'..'date_to')
  end

  def parsed_date(date_string, default)
    Date.parse(date_string)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
  end
end
```

Requests_controller.rb

```
  def index
    # if params[:search] == nil
    #   @all_requests = Request.all
    # else
      @search = RequestSearch.new(params[:search])
      @all_requests = @search.scope
  end
```

Materializecss DOM

```
<input type="text" name="" id="search_date_from" value="2017-08-13"
 placeholder="From date" class="datepicker picker__input" readonly="" 
tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="search_date_from_root">
```

Comment: `Request.where(:date => date_from..date_to)` - remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RequestSearch
  attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

  # use keyword args instead
  def initialize(date_from: nil, date_to: nil, **kwargs)
    # You need to use `@` to set instance vars
    @date_from = parsed_date(date_from)
    @date_to = parsed_date(date_to)
  end

  def scope
    Request.where(date: date_from..date_to)
  end

  # reduce the arity by setting the default in the method
  # definition
  def parsed_date(date_string, default = Date.today.to_s)
    Date.parse(date_string)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
  end
end
```

Comment: I got this error:
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
 def initialize(date_from: nil, date_to: nil, **kwargs)

Is it because I have passed in the whole params[:search] in the controller?